# History API (scroll -> replaceState) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, html5-history-api, history-api, history

Обновил jQuery и jq-ui и теперь вижу предупреждение:

> Throttling history state changes to prevent the browser from hanging.

множественное появление при скроллах

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    "use strict";

    history.state.scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    history.state.scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    window.history.replaceState(history.state, '', history.state.url);
    });
```

Как тогда мне обновлять скролы в истории ?

Comment: Но зачем? Что мешает вам обновлять не всегда при скролле, а хотя бы раз в секунду, например?

Comment: @andreymal 1 секунда это долго и такое событие будет постоянно выполняться даже когда изменений нету. У меня быстрое приложение и в нем я очень быстро тыкаю курсором) Когда не туда тыкнул нужно сразу вернуться назад.

Comment: Это звучит максимально странно. Вы зачем-то делаете игру на базе History API, что ли? Или что там у вас такое быстрое, что аж быстрее секунды? o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать debounce/throttle для моих целей.

Comment: Я именно это вам и предлагал...

Comment: @andreymal, надо было разжевать ))) Ответ ему дали на cyberforum. Но уже после того, как он получил ответ здесь от Вас. А нужен был просто код, который можно скопипастить ))

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd я и сам могу написать по докам! Ответ был абстрактный, то что мне и так было известно. А на форуме человек написал конкретный метод (функцию/плагин) которым это можно реализовать. Конечно - да, некую часть хотелось увидеть для копи) Типа тела тех фун-й